# SQL Server - Export encrypted data (Column Encryption Setting=enabled) using bcp.exe utility

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption, export

I need to export the table with encrypted columns into a text file. Encrypted data should be exported as plain text and not encrypted.

Hello all.

I need to do some aggregation operations over encrypted columns in SQL Server (data is encrypted by built-in SQL Server 2017 Always Encrypted feature). I have found a way how to do it - export the table content in some text file and then import this text file into some table. It will allow to do any operations over the data because it will not be encrypted anymore.

It works perfectly when I export this data manually from SSMS using **[Save Results As...]** option and then import the file using **BULK INSERT** command.

The next step that I need is that I want to do it automatically using the stored procedure. I have found an information that it can be done via **XP_CMDSHELL** command that calls **bcp.exe** utility. And here the problem begins.

This utility is run by user that runs SQL Server process. I have installed a security certificate for that user and I expected that the exported data via bcp.exe utility would be decrypted. But unfortunately it is not.

Some info about user that runs SQL Server process:

**1)** It has sysadmin server role;

**2)** It has installed security .pfx certificate for accessing the encrypted data

**3)** When I log in as the SQL Server user, connect to the database using additional parameter **Column Encryption Setting=enabled**, select the data from table with encrypted columns - I see the decrypted data.

The commands that I am using:

```
DECLARE @bcp_cmd4 VARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE @exe_path4 VARCHAR(200) =
' cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ & ';

SET @bcp_cmd4 =  @exe_path4 + 
'bcp.exe "SELECT * FROM [Table]" queryout ' +
' "C:\Dir\Data.csv" -T -c -t, -r \n';

PRINT @bcp_cmd4;

EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @bcp_cmd4;
```

This command exports the table data, but encrypted columns remain encrypted, so I cannot import it and do the further operations over it.

Could someone assist with the solution?

Comment: How your data  are encrypted, using what tecnology?

Comment: @sepupic: Encryption seems to be built in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, it is a built-in SQL Server 2017 Always Encrypted feature. I have updated a post description.